# Can't get KeyDown event on Tabpage

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a TabControl with several TabPages, each containing a series of PictureBox. I want to be able to navigate with the arrow keys inside those TabPages. I tried to give `.Focus()` to the TabPage when the user selects it, and then trap the `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown` events, but it does not work. I've put a breakpoint at the `PreviewKeyDown` event handler, and it is not event reached.

Here is the activation of the TabPage :

```
  Sub TilesetsTab_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TilesetsTab.Selected
        Dim myTab As TabControl = CType(sender, TabControl)
        If myTab.TabCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Active.Tileset = Project.Tileset(CInt(myTab.SelectedTab.Tag))
        Active.Tileset.Tab.Focus()
    End Sub
```

And here is the Key event handlers

```
Sub Tab_KeyPreviewDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Tab.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then e.IsInputKey = True
End Sub


Sub Tab_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Tab.KeyDown 'BUG
    Dim TilesWidth As Integer = Me.Tab.Width \ Me.ScreenSize
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            If Active.Tile.Index = 0 Then Exit Sub
            Me.Tile(Active.Tile.Index - 1).Selected()
        Case Keys.Right
            If Active.Tile.Index = Project.Tileset.Count - 1 Then Exit Sub
            Me.Tile(Active.Tile.Index + 1).Selected()
        Case Keys.Up
            If Active.Tile.Index < TilesWidth Then Exit Sub
            Me.Tile(Active.Tile.Index - TilesWidth).Selected()
        Case Keys.Down
            If Active.Tile.Index + TilesWidth > Active.Tileset.Count - 1 Then Exit Sub
            Me.Tile(Active.Tile.Index + TilesWidth).Selected()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Why can't I fire a KeyDown event on the TabPage ?

Comment: Both of these event worked in my testing. Perhaps you are creating the TabControl dynamically and not creating the event handlers as well? Try it with a new project and slowly add/remove parts until you find your issue. Without more code, I cannot see the issue.

Comment: @Steve : I don't know why the answer posted yesterday by someone (and the comments I made) were deleted, but the guy said that TabPages could not have focus, it was restricted to TabControl.

Following his advice, I shifted the `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown` event handlers to TabControl and it worked. I'm losing the arrow navigation between TabPages, but that's alright with me.

Comment: Good to know. Add that as an answer and accept it to close out this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the answer posted yesterday by someone (and the comments I made) were deleted, but it was said that TabPages could not have focus, and that it is restricted to TabControl. Following that advice, I shifted the `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown` event handlers to TabControl events and it worked.

I'm losing some of the arrow navigation between TabPages, but it suits me.

Comment: If you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

> Some key presses, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are
> typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered
> input key presses. For example, by default, a Button control ignores
> the arrow keys. Pressing the arrow keys typically causes the focus to
> move to the previous or next control.